# Implementing Separate Authentication for React JS Users in Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, axios, fortify

I am currently working on a project that utilizes Laravel for admin management and API services, while ReactJS handles the user interface. The default Laravel Fortify authentication system is exclusively used for admin login, and I have implemented Sanctum for managing token-based API authentication for React JS users.

I am seeking guidance on how to implement separate authentication for React JS users without modifying Laravel Fortify's admin login functionality. My objective is to establish a distinct authentication mechanism for users while maintaining a unified API server.
This is my approach:

**configuring cors.php**

```
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**handle login from separate controller**

```
    public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email'=>'required|string|email',
            'password'=>'required|string',
        ]);
        //i am missing a guard right ??
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        //shouldn't i return a token ??    
         return response()->json(['message'=>'sucess']);
     }

        return response()->json('failed');
    }
```

**adding route in route/api.php**

```
Route::post('/login',[ActivatedUserAPIController::class,'login']);
```

**sending request using axios**

```
onSubmit={async (values)=>{
            try{
              await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
              await axios.post('/api/login',values) //values are email and password
              .then(response=>console.log(response));
            }catch(e){
              console.log(e)
            }
          }
```

when Using admin credentials it returns true, and false for other users. I am aware that i need to implement guards, however i don't know if i should use web guards with session cookies, or api guard ? I am confused how to implement the authentication.

Any suggestions or insights on achieving this separation of authentication would be greatly appreciated.